# Dive into the assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Function in `c`:

```
PHPAPI char *php_pcre_replace(char *regex,   int regex_len,
                              char *subject, int subject_len,
                              zval *replace_val, int is_callable_replace,
                              int *result_len, int limit, int *replace_count TSRMLS_DC)
{
    pcre_cache_entry    *pce;               /* Compiled regular expression */

    /* Compile regex or get it from cache. */
    if ((pce = pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache(regex, regex_len TSRMLS_CC)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ....
}
```

Its assembly:

```
php5ts!php_pcre_replace:
1015db70 8b442408        mov     eax,dword ptr [esp+8]
1015db74 8b4c2404        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+4]
1015db78 56              push    esi
1015db79 8b74242c        mov     esi,dword ptr [esp+2Ch]
1015db7d 56              push    esi
1015db7e 50              push    eax
1015db7f 51              push    ecx
1015db80 e8cbeaffff      call    php5ts!pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache (1015c650)
1015db85 83c40c          add     esp,0Ch
1015db88 85c0            test    eax,eax
1015db8a 7502            jne     php5ts!php_pcre_replace+0x1e (1015db8e)

php5ts!php_pcre_replace+0x1c:
1015db8c 5e              pop     esi
1015db8d c3              ret
```

The c function call `pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache(regex, regex_len TSRMLS_CC)` corresponds to `1015db7d~1015db80` which pushes the 3 parameters to the stack and call it.

But my doubt is,among so many registers,how does the compiler decide to use `eax`,`ecx` and `esi`(this is special,as it's restored before using,why?) as the intermediate to carry to the stack?

There must be some hidden indication in c that tells the compiler to do it this way,right?

Comment: Mh, why? You could do this optimization outside of the compiler -- walk the code, figure what gets set and referenced where and when, and then do an optimization leading to good register usage. If you can do that outside of the compiler, then it's not in the source code, or language. In today's world, most native compilers do quite advanced optimizations that can make it very hard to understand what the code does (or what the source code and the generated opcodes have in common (or not), and why (not)).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no hidden indication.

This is a typical strategy for generating 80x86 instructions used by many compiler implementations, `C` and otherwise.  For example, the 1980s Intel Fortran-77 compiler, when optimization was turned on, did the same thing.

That is uses `eax` and `ecx` preferentially is probably an artifact of avoiding use of `esi` and `edi` since those registers cannot directly be used to load byte operands.

Why not `ebx` and `edx`?  Well, those are preferred by many code generators for holding intermediate pointers in evaluating complex structure evaluation, which is to say, there isn't much reason at all.  The compiler just looked for two available registers to use and overwrote them to buffer the values.

Why not reuse `eax` like this?:

```
   push    esi
   mov     eax,dword ptr [esp+2Ch]
   push    eax
   mov     eax,dword ptr [esp+8]
   push    eax
   mov     eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
   push    eax
```

Because that causes pipeline stalls waiting for `eax` to complete previous memory cycles, in 80x86s since the 80586 (maybe 80486—it's too long ago to be sure off the top of my head).

The x86 architecture is a strange beast.  Each register, though promoted as being "general purpose" by Intel, has its quirks (`cx`/`ecx` is tied to the `loop` instruction for example, and `eax:edx` is tied to the multiply instruction).  That combined with the peculiar ways to optimize execution to avoid cache misses and pipeline stalls often leads to inscrutable generated code by a code generator which factors all that in.